# What is the "Cal 22" contract?

Tags: stock-markets, terminology

As far as I understood so far, it's a contract traded on the stock exchange.
Is this correct and what does Cal 22 stand for?

> GERMAN – Cal 22 gains in line with carbon

[EDIT] context: text on energy markets

> the prices of Cal22 Power Ita, which closed last Friday at around €56/MWh, are only around €4/MWh higher than the average of the last 5 years, excluding 2020

Thanks!

Comment: Some more context would be helpful here. "Cal 22" could be part of the name of a specific futures contract where "22" refers to 2022, but there is not enough to say for certain. Example: G PXE CZ BL CAL-22 is a gas futures product with physical delivery in 2022.

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 I've edited my question with another example from the text I'm translating. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here "Cal 22" refers to a futures contract with delivery in 2022. One source of more information is the European Energy Exchange (EEX).

So for example, this link should bring up the Italian Power Futures (i.e., the item referenced in "the prices of Cal22 Power Ita, which closed last Friday at around €56/MWh"), where today (Monday) we can see the baseload Cal-22 last price is given as 55.20.

https://www.eex.com/en/market-data/power/futures#%7B%22snippetpicker%22%3A%22EEX%20Italian%20Power%20Futures%22%7D

Comment: all clear, thanks a lot! Btw I upvoted your answer but got the following message: "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score." @C8H10N4O2